# imageWithData method problem

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I have a UIImageView,while loading it for the first time i should not have any image so i will make the image nil.

```
self.myImageView.image = nil;
```

on pressing a button i need the image to be loaded using the imageWithData method as i have a image in NSData.While i am trying to do this the application crashes.I even tried allocating and using with initWithData that is of no help.

```
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData];
```

But, wheni use this method while loading for the first time using my data and then try to put it into Image view with the button press it works fine.

Please help me regarding this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the scope of Variables. in view did load data was correct but in other method i was not getting the image so i used self.myImageData in view did load as well as in IB action method, now it works fine.

Note: It would be diffcult to find the answer for this question in the comment so i have made it as answer and accepted it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:myImageData]];
```

Update:

If the imageView is created without using `initWithImage:` imageView.image becomes nil by default.

Comment: i tried it but again at this poing the application crashes.i am not understanding what problem i am having. if i put any image using imageNamed method it will be fine even if in the beginning there is nil but not in the case of imageWithData

Comment: Pls check your imageData then

Comment: image data is fine as i have mentioned in the beginning in view did load if i give self.myImageView.myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData] and then in the IBAction method of button i give the same thing then there is no crashes.Image data is proper i have checked.

Comment: I dont think u need to make self.imageview.image = nil. It does not contain any image by default so why make it nil.

Comment: crashes again ...i tried all combinations but when i put self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData] in view did load it works fine

Comment: @7KV7 hi..i solved the problem the problem was the scope.. in view did load data was correct but in other method i was not getting the image so i used self.myImageData in view did load as well as in IB action now it works fine.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: gr8. Happy coding :) Pls vote-up if u found the answers useful and accept them so that u get more responses.